# Screenshots are coming black/Improper on using xamarin test cloud

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, nunit

Screenshots are coming black/Improper on using xamarin test cloud while the screenshots are coming perfect while running the test on local device or emulator.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you mean by this? How about the code that you're using that might be related to this problem?

Comment: The test are run Properly,the screenshots are also saved locally when running these test on local device or emulator. But when i upload these test cases on xamarin test cloud, then my test are running fine,but the screenshots that are coming are black.I don't know why is this happening.I have tried with other .apkFile but that is working fine.